# Apache rewrite underscores to hyphens except when preceded by forward slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to come up the proper RewriteRule or RewriteCond to change underscores to hyphens except when the underscore is preceded by a forward slash.  I have the following rules in place which changes all underscores to hyphens regardless of what precedes it:

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=underscores:Yes,N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:underscores} ^Yes$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What do I need to modify to prevent '/_' from being changed to '/-'?

Example:

`http://host/_test_location/_test_page` gets changed to
`http://host/_test-location/_test-page` NOT
`http://host/-test-location/-test-page`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this slightly modified rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])_+(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=underscores:Yes,N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:underscores} ^Yes$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I must be completely missing the boat.  I have anubhava's code in Apache and now it is not replacing any underscores with hyphens

Comment: I had tested before posting here. Try `RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])_+(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=underscores:Yes,N]`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `*` to `+` in your first regex:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/([^/_]+)_+(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2-%3 [E=underscores:Yes,N]
```

The `+` means it must match at least one. So the sting `_test` doesn't have any non-"_" characters before the `_` and so will not match.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and unfortunately it still changes /_test to /-test

Comment: @BradRodgers Are you sure? I tested it in a vanilla apache install and a blank htaccess file and it works. Did you clear your browser's cache?

Comment: @BradRodgers Actually, the second _ still gets converted, try adding a `/?` in front and remove the `^`

Comment: can you post a new codeblock with your suggestions.  I'm not getting it working and perhaps I'm not fully understanding your suggestions.  Thanks!